# How to hide/remove WatchOS 9's .sheet cancel button?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-9

Previous to watchOS 9 you could present a sheet without any out of the box way to cancel or dismiss.  However starting in watchOS 9 presenting a sheet also presents a cancel button in the top left of the navigation bar.  How can I remove this and handle dismissing myself?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("show sheet") {
                isShowingSheet.toggle()
            }
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            Text("Sheet 1")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would using `.fullScreenCover` instead do the trick?

Comment: @ScottM `.fullScreenCover` comes with a cancel button as well.

Comment: `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline), .navigationTitle(" ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue here, tried an empty view in a ToolBarItem but did not work.
I ended up using this:

```
NavigationView {
 // Your stuff here
}
.navigationTitle("")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

What you do is that you set an empty title, and you tell it to go at the same place as of the cancel button.

PS:it looks like @Kurt Lane was a bit faster in the comment. Credits to him.

Comment: FYI: This seems to work also in WatchOS 10. Thanks!